# Number of homomorphism from $S_3$ to $\mathbb Z_6$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Total number of homomorphism from $S_3$ to $\mathbb Z_6$ , $S_3$ to $S_4$ and how to determine?

Comment: Do you know what the kernel of a homomorphism is?

Comment: Normal subgroup whose elements mapped to 0. Should I think about 1st Isomorphism Theorem?

Comment: Well, do you know what the normal subgroups of $S_3$ are?

Comment: A3 should be normal as of index 2. Then?

Comment: Ok, so what are the possible images of such a homomorphism (now using the isomorphism theorem)?

Comment: not getting.....help please

Comment: According to the first isomorphism theorem, the image of such a homomorphism will be a quotient of $S_3$. What possible such quotients are there?

Comment: S3/A3,S3/{e}......Anything else??

Comment: One more, $S_3/S_3$. What are the orders of these quotients, and can you describe them in a simpler way?

Comment: This [question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/218519/ways-s-3-can-act-on-a-set-of-4-elements) might give you an idea about how to go about it. (It is looking at the number of homomorphisms from $S_3 \to S_4$, so it's not the same, but it might help!)

Comment: Is the ans 3. Is the question boils down to the no of normal subgroups of S3?

Comment: @EuReka, that is not the case in general. $S_3$ has only three possible kernels, but as in the case above ($S_3 \to S_4$), there are 24 possible homomorphisms.

Comment: @Robert Please explain... How 24 homomorphism?

Comment: The problem and solution are explained in the link to my first comment above. My point is: You need to consider all your possible kernels and then look at them in a case by case basis: how many homomorphisms do you get when the kernel is $A_3$? Is it possible to have any homomorphisms with kernel $\{e\}$? We are assured the zero homomorphism in this case which is when kernel is $\S_3$.

Comment: Robert Please Give me a proper Answer with a explanation.I am not getting your point.......

Comment: This question has been asked [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/261587/how-do-i-find-the-number-of-group-homomorphisms-from-s-3-to-mathbbz-6-math) and [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/152853/count-the-number-group-homomorphisms-from-s-3-to-z-6z)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How many homomorphisms do we have from $S_3 \to \mathbb Z_6$?

If $\varphi : S_3 \to \mathbb Z_6$, then $\mathbb S_3/\ker \varphi \cong \varphi(S_3)$ by the first isomorphism theorem. Consider our possible kernels: $\{1\}, A_3, S_3$.

If $\ker \varphi = \{1\}$, then this would mean that $S_3 \cong \mathbb Z_6$ which is not true (for if it were it would imply $S_3$ is commutative, which it isn't). So there are **no** homomorphisms with kernel $\{1\}$

If $\ker \varphi = S_3$ then we have that $\varphi$ is the zero map, so this yields **one** homomorphism.

What happens if $\ker \varphi = A_3$? Well observe that $S_3/A_3 \cong \mathbb Z_2$. How many ways can you embed $\mathbb Z_2$ in $\mathbb Z_6$?

Comment: I dont understand your last sentence. I am expecting a answer for $S_3$ to $S_4$

Comment: Yes. $\varphi : S_3 \to \mathbb Z_6$ but we are looking at the case when the kernel is $A_3$. By the first isomorphism theorem, we have $\mathbb Z_2 \cong S_3/A_3 \cong \varphi(S_3)$, so it reduces us to the case when $\varphi : \mathbb Z_2 \to \mathbb Z_6$ and if you recall, this is uniquely determined by $\varphi$'s action on $\overline 1$. So you get two homomorphisms: the zero map (which we already counted) and $\varphi(1) = \overline 3$ (all others yield a contradiction). Hence this yields **one** homomorphism, i.e., you can embed $\mathbb Z_2$ into $\mathbb Z_6$ in one way.

Comment: What about $S_3$ to  $S_4$?